# How to add aws amplify to an existing Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, aws-amplify

I had an existing and working Angular project. As a recent request, I need to use the Aws Amplify in my project. I am struggling with add Aws amplify to my project because Amplify only has option Amplify CLI to init a completely new Angular project. Does anyone face this issue before and had a solution, please advise me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

The Amplify CLI does not actually create a new Angular project, or any other type of project.  Instead, it adds an amplify directory to your existing project along with an aws-exports file (it can also add graphql code if you integrate appsync).  You can use the CLI to spin up new resources and integrate them into your project via the Amplify library.  You can also use the Amplify library without using the Amplify CLI at all by following the instructions in the Amplify docs under [Manual Setup](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#manual-setup).

Comment: What's the motivation for you to use amplify. Just for authentication?

Comment: What is an amplify directory? Does amplify create a physical directory?